# Expanging Search Box covering up links on navbar

Tags: javascript, css, search, z-index

Trying a Javascript out that is supposed to start out with a search monocle icon and when you click on it, the search box expands out over the navigation bar. Now that works, but the problem is even when the search box is not over the navbar, you can't click on any of the links in the navbar. Probably because the search box is still 'there', even though it's not.

I think it's something in my css file, but I've tried a number of modifications, to no avail. Only way it seems to work is to make the search bar really small in width. I made a sample of the issue here: http://somm.icorp.net/search-test.html

Any idea how to make this work regarding getting the bar to expand correctly and not cover up the links until the search icon is clicked upon?

Comment: Show the code of what you have tried. That will make it easier on those that that want to help.

Comment: Can you provide the code.  (HTML, CSS and any Javascript).  It'll be helpful if you can make a jsfiddle.

Comment: instead of using z-index to change the display of the input try using display: none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `z-index` on `#input` is too high initially (it's 5). Change that to `-1`.

Edit:

What I did to find your problem: In Chrome, right click on the area you are expecting to click on normally and select "inspect element" from the context menu. That will highlight the item you are *actually* clicking on. Notice that the `z-index` property is higher than the buttons when the `active` class is not on.

[image]

Comment: Azium, that was the trick alright. I didn't even know you could do negative z-indexes. So thanks for the important and valuable lesson.